# My passport authentication function is not running

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I have the function (see code) everything is working except the user.comparehashandpass() function.

This is a nodejs express mongoose app. It was working fine a while back but I don't know what went wrong

the code works except the user.compareHashAndPass()

```
 passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }

       user.compareHashandpass(password, user.password, function (err, 
res) {
    console.log("code reaches here")
    if (err) {
        return done(err);
    } else {
        return done(err, false, {
            message: 'Incorrect password'
        });
    }
  });


  return done(null, user);
});
  }
));
```

I have included the model.method in the model file. As I said, it used to work fine a while ago.

```
userSchema.methods.compareHashandpass =  function(password, hash, cb){
            bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, res) {
            if (err) return cb(err);
            if (res === false) {
            return false
            } else {
            return true
            }
            });
        };
```

It is supposed to return message: "Incorrect Password", in the event the password in the DB and the password provided by the user do not check out. It is only authenticating the username. It returns the "user" even when the password is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you return true/false instead callback (`cb`) try:

```
userSchema.methods.compareHashandpass =  function(password, hash, cb){
            bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, res) {
            if (err) return cb(err);
            if (res === false) {
              cb(null,false);
            } else {
              cb(nuul, true);
            }
            });
        };
```